# Read, Store and Access Temporary Files (BASH)

Tags: bash, expr

I want to loaded a temporary files with the bunch of numbers from input file.
The format of the script is "testing -row/-col [input file]".
The input file mostly just a bunch of random numbers like

```
1 2 3 4
3 3 5 6
9 4 4 2
```

My code below is trying to grab this input file as argument and then "cat" these numbers into a new temporary files. From there, I'm trying to find average value of the row from this temporary files.

```
FILENAME=$2
TMP=./TMP2.$$
cat $FILENAME > $TMP

#average row 
function avg_row {
while read -a row  
do
    total=0
    sum=0
    for i in "${rows[@]}"
    do
         eum=`expr $sum + $i`
         total=`expr $total + 1`
    done
    average=`expr $sum / $total`
    echo $average
done < $TMP
}
```

However, even though when I "cat" the TMP files it display exactly the same like testing_file, when I run the script it prints

```
 expr: division by zero
 expr: division by zero
 expr: division by zero
```

Any suggestions or idea on why this could happen? Thank you.

Comment: Isn't it by saying "cat $FILENAME > $TMP", it automatically read the entire file? I'm new with bash, so sorry if I'm wrong. What's the proper way then?

Comment: No, that's just an implementation of `cp "$FILENAME" "$TMP"`. It has nothing to do with reading the file. Just use `$FILENAME` where you are using `$TMP` in your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. Your function reads in array `row` but then attempts to access a nonexistent array `rows`.  Because `rows` has no entries, `total` is never incremented and the division is division-by-zero.
2. This line updates `eum`, not `sum`:

   ```
   eum=`expr $sum + $i`
   ```

Also, it is not clear why the contents of $FILENAME are copied before they are read.  I will assume that you have a good reason for this.

A corrected function looks like:

```
function avg_row {
while read -a row  
do
    total=0
    sum=0
    for i in "${row[@]}"
    do
         sum=`expr $sum + $i`
         total=`expr $total + 1`
    done
    average=`expr $sum / $total`
    echo $average
done < $TMP
```

This produces the output:

```
$ avg_row
2
4
4
```

#### Modernized bash version

Both backticks and `expr` are archaic.  A more modern bash version of the function is:

```
avg_row2() {
while read -a row
do
    sum=0
    for i in "${row[@]}"
    do
        ((sum += i))
    done
    echo $((sum / ${#row[@]}))
done < $TMP
}
```

This produces the same output as before:

```
$ avg_row2
2
4
4
```

#### awk version

The same thing can be accomplished in awk:

```
$ awk '{s=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) s+=$i; print int(s/NF);}' filename
2
4
4
```

Unlike bash, awk can do floating point arithmetic:

```
$ awk '{s=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) s+=$i; print s/NF;}' filename
2.5
4.25
4.75
```

Comment: Wow, yeah my bad that I didn't scan my code carefully. I was too confused with the calling temporary files part. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Gross hack: `sum=$(IFS='+'; echo $(( ${nums[*]} )) )`.